# duplicate MIME type "text/html"?

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I have this in Nginx configuration files

```
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

but Nginx give error when starting up

```
[warn]: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:25
```

What is actually duplicate to `text/html`? Is it `text/plain`?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

For the option `gzip_types`, the mime-type `text/html` is always included by default, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Relevant docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule#gzip_types `Enables compression for additional MIME-types besides "text/html". "text/html" is always compressed.`

Comment: the same applies to i.a. `charset_types`

Comment: That link is broken, new link: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types

Comment: The same applies to `sub_filter_types` as mentioned in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter_types: *Enables string replacement in responses with the specified MIME types in addition to “text/html”.*