# How to deploy Node project to elastic beanstalk and make it work with nginx?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've made a simple Node server that respond to a simple website on a separate project. I've tested them on my localhost and they both work perfectly (CORS working). So, I decided to upload them to AWS being the Node project on elastic beanstalk and the website to S3. The website works, makes the request to the elastic beanstalk environment but it doesn't get an answer (time out). By the elastic beanstalk logs I can see the Node server started without a problem but it doesn't receive the requests. So I figured it out that the problem is probably on nginx that I didn't make any changes (only the default created by aws). How do I make the nginx forward the request to the Node server correctly?

I've tried adding some config to .ebextensions folder but it didn't work (not sure if I did it right).

Also, nginx error.log prints:
`2015/11/24 03:23:01 [warn] 15214#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf:42` that I've tried to solve unsuccessfully.

Thanks.

Comment: the error is irrelevant. isn't there another error in the eb-activity log? anyway, nginx is supposed to work out of the box in elastic beanstalk. nothing you need to do. it should automatically direct requests to the node. If no error is in the log, then it must be a permission issue

Comment: @Tal the eb-activity log seems fine! all activities starts and finishes without any problem, no errors there. Which permissions are you thinking of?

Comment: it's usually a bad security group that prevents entry to port 80. try to telnet your app and see if it's open: `telnet myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com 80`

Comment: @Tal I did that and it connected!

Comment: In that case, all is connected and your app simply doesn't respond. Have a look at the nginx and your server logs, there must be something there.

Comment: @Tal I swear there's nothing else. nginx/access.log is empty, nginx/error.log shows only the MIME type error and nodejs/nodejs.log shows only the logs I've set to know it started

Comment: I'd contact AWS support for that :)

Comment: I've changed a couple of things and I think I've solved that problem! Now I have another one, but thanks for your help @Tal

Comment: "I've changed a couple of things and I think I've solved that problem" but you didn't post what you changed :(. Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your elastic beanstalk. It's your nginx problem inside your instance. I'm guessing you are deploying the nodejs express application. So, what you should do is to `ssh -i <pemfile> <ec2user>@<host>` into your instance. And change your nginx configuration. Based on what people has discussed in this: [duplicate MIME type “text/html”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475472/3781320)
Just remove `text/html` in `gzip_types`, because nginx has it installed by default.

Comment: Also, if you find a solution, please provide your answer as soon as possible. So that other people won't ask duplicated question. I spend more time to figure this problem because of this.@felipeAVasconcelos

Comment: I have removed text/html in gzip_types but no luck.